# python: why am I not exiting while loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can't find anything applicable to the problem I have here. If there is, please point me toward it.
Anyway, as a new one to python, I can't  understand why my output here keeps repeating indefinitely.

```
from random import randint
dollars = int(input("How many dollars do you have? "))

maxdollars = dollars
countatmax = 0
count = 0

while dollars > 0:
    count += 1
    diceone = randint(0, 6)
    dicetwo = randint(0, 6)
    if diceone + dicetwo == 7:
        dollars + 4
    else:
        dollars - 1
    if dollars != maxdollars:
        mostdollars = dollars
        countatmax = count
    print "You are broke after " + str(count) + " rolls.\n" + \
          "You should have quit after " + str(countatmax) + \
          " rolls when you had $" + str(maxdollars) + "."
```

Comment: You also need to clarify what "keeps repeating indefinitely" means. If you put a large number in as an input, your print statement will print at least once for each time. So if you input 1000 you will print at least 1000 times.

Comment: You aren't actually modifying `dollars`. You will need `dollars += 4` and `dollars -= 1`.

Comment: A few strategically placed `print` statements would go a long way to helping you solve this for yourself.

Comment: In addition, you should move your `print` statement to outside your `while` loop, and use `if dollars> maxdollars:`

Comment: @BryanOakley, can you elaborate a little and help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like Karin said, you are not changing the value of dollars with these statements:

```
if diceone + dicetwo == 7:
    dollars + 4
else:
    dollars - 1
```

since the amount of "dollars" never gets changed, your while loop will loop forever (dollars will always be greater than zero) assuming that the user inputs a positive value

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

`while dollars > 0:
    count += 1
    diceone = randint(0, 6)
    dicetwo = randint(0, 6)
    if diceone + dicetwo == 7:
        dollars + 4
    else:
        dollars - 1`

`dollars + 4` is simply adding 4 to the dollar amount. So, if initial amount is $100 then  `dollars + 4`  will always equal $104. The same is true with  `dollars - 1` . It will always equal $99 for this case.

To understand it a little better, try this: `dollars = dollars + 4`
This will take the previous dollars amount (say $104 now), add $4 to it, then store that amount back into itself with the updated amount now at $108.

Since the dollar amount never decreases, an infinite loop occurs.

A shortcut to this is `dollars+=4` or `dollars-=1`